CLI tool in an NPM package doesn't execute under Node
I would like to publish a NPM package with a CLI utility in it. In the package.json, I have the following line:
"bin": "index.js"
When I install the package on Windows, a batch file is being generated under Roaming\npm, it's called mypackage.cmd, and the final line goes:
"%dp0%\node_modules\mypackage\index.js"   %*
It's not executing the script under Node.js, it's executing the JavaScript file as is - not the desired result. On my dev box, for one, the default association for .js files is Visual Studio Code, not Node. Looking at other modules' generated batch scripts, I see that the final line is different:
"%_prog%"  "%dp0%\node_modules\anotherpackage\bin\somescript.js" %*
where _prog is initialized to the Node executable.
I want the bin script to execute explicitly under Node. What is missing in my package (presumably in package.json)?

To reproduce, create a directory. Create the following package.json in it:
{"name": "boo", "version": "1.0.0", "bin": "index.js"}
Create the following index.js in it:
process.exit(0);
Run the following on the command line in that directory:
npm i -g .
Then see the contents of boo.cmd (on Windows):
type %APPDATA%\npm\boo.cmd
And note the lack of _prog on the bottommost line.

Add #! /usr/bin/env node to the first line of index.js

What about Windows? And besides, other packages are doing it somehow...

It's the same, npm will handle it during install.

Checked, the logic in npm (specifically in writeShim() in module cmd-shim) reads the target script file and checks for the hashbang. Write an answer, I'll accept.

Just add #! /usr/bin/env node to the first line of index.js
